# Dynamic Content Markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Is there a way to provide Dynamic Content in posts? Specifically, it would be nice to include the ability to have up-to-date statistics in a post if you're talking about the number of results in a feed.

Perhaps if you include a link to an RSS feed <sup>([example](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=extruder&sort=votes))</sup>, then the resulting markup would include a citation with the number of results.

Using the example link above (as of 06/15/2018) would look like:

Markdown:

`[Here is the original link text](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=extruder&sort=votes)`

Server could check for `(.*?)/feeds/(.*?)` (ignore my crude regex) in href. XPath `count(//entry)` should do the trick for the count.

Markup:

```
<a href="https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=extruder&sort=votes">
    Here is the original link text
    <sup class="dc-count">[30]</sup>
</a>
```

Resulting in:

[Here is the original link text<sup>[30]</sup>](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=extruder&sort=votes)

I'm sure there are a lot of other use cases such as using Site Analytics, but this seemed like possibly the most practical and immediately useful use case to me.

Comment: In which usecase would it make sense to link to a stackexchange feed from a stackexchange question or answer?

Comment: I realized now that I meant to post this to StackExchange Meta, but @3D Printing we have posted multiple Meta posts regarding our Beta status with various goals and how we can try to achieve the goals. Typically we add links with quick searches/feeds which can be used to chip away at problem areas. It would be helpful for these posts to have a live count in the post next to a target count.